# Health Insurance dual UK and Canadian Citizen long term stay in France

Tags: united-kingdom, france, canada, ehic

I am Canadian with UK passport living in France for 10 months.  We have been here for 3 already.  I would like to know if I and my dependents qualify for an EHIC card.  We are not residents of France, we are residents of Yukon Canada.  I think the answer is no based on questions already asked on this exchange, but want to double check.  Thank you.
Dominic Bradford

Answer (score 2):

You have to be covered by an EU health scheme to get an EHIC.  Because you are not a resident of the UK, you are not eligible for the NHS.  You might buy insurance in France, though, while you are there; this would, I believe, entitle you to get an EHIC so your emergency care is covered in case you travel elsewhere in Europe during your stay in France.

If you have coverage in Canada, you should check whether it is valid in France.